# Find the prime which divides $f(n)+f(n+100)$ terms of Fibonacci sequence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f(n)$ denote $n$th number in the Fibonacci sequence. Find a two digit prime such that $p$ divides $f(n) + f(n+100)$ for all $n$.

Well to be honest I have no idea how to solve this problem so I don't really have anything to show for my attempts.
Well I did try to play around with the recursion a bit but it ended with just a jumbled up nothing burger. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Try to find the explicit equation for $f(n)$ that expresses it directly as a function of $n$.

Comment: Hint: if you find a prime that divides both $f(0)+f(100)$ and $f(1) + f(101)$, then ...

Comment: to find f(100) should not be a part of solution because it would be a very big number as well as there will exist multiple common primes in those two sets because of the properties of fibonnaci sequence

Comment: @AnayGautam This is your third question here. It’s time that you start using MathJax while typing your questions. It’s really not that hard: you just enclose your formulas in $ signs, for the most part.

Comment: You could look for a two-digit prime $p$ such that [A001175](https://oeis.org/A001175)$(p)$ divides $200$ but not $100$.

Comment: Or you could look at [OEIS sequence A063726](https://oeis.org/A063726).

Comment: One observes that even if you know $p$ divides two such terms, $p$ divides all of them. Then, the best you can go without depending on lists or other such things is finding $f(51)+f(-49) = f(51)+f(49)$

Comment: Well the point of the question is to not use any additional prerequisites other than the properties of fibbonnaci sequence to solve the problem.

Comment: It is from a olympiad based exam thats why we cant use pre-recorded factorization/fibonnaci sequence lists and as for the context I think I have provided enough in the original question itself.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Anay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us consider Fibonacci sequence modulo $41$. One can look up [the Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) of $41$, it is equal to $40$, but actually (the $0$-th and then) every $20$-th Fibonacci number is divisible by $41$. Here are Fibonacci numbers modulo $41$:

$$0, 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,14,7,21,28,8,36,3,39,1,40,0$$

The next two numbers are $$40, 40.$$ This can be interpreted as $$-1,-1.$$ So the numbers repeat, but with opposite sign.

This means that $F_n$ and $F_{n+20+40k}$ are opposite modulo $41$ for any non-negative integer $k$. Or, $F_n + F_{n+20+40k}$ is divisible by $41$. Putting $k=2$ we get that $F_n + F_{n+100}$ is divisible by $41$ for any $n$.

**Note.** How did we guess to consider $41$? From [the list of Fibonacci numbers and their prime factorizations](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fibonacci/fibtable.html). I’d like to see the solution without using such data.

**Edit**

Here I will prove why $41$ is the only two digit prime with such property. I will use some of the facts about Pisano periods, as well as some other facts about Fibonacci numbers:

- If $p$ is prime of the form $10k\pm1$ then its Pisano period is the divisor of $p-1$.
- If $p$ is prime of the form $10k\pm3$ then its Pisano period is the divisor of $2(p+1)$.
- Zeros go in a Pisano period over equal segments.
- There are no zeros in $4$ first numbers after the initial zero in any Pisano period for all two-digit numbers (this one is obvious).
- For every prime number $p$ there is a Fibonacci number that is divisible by $p$ (for example, one of the $F_{p-1}$, $F_{p}$, or $F_{p+1}$).

So, let’s take $n$ such that $p\mid F_n$. Since $p\mid F_n+F_{n+100}$, we get $p\mid F_{n+100}$. A zero occured in the Fibonacci sequence modulo $p$ after $100$ steps. This means that **a divisor of Pisano period of $p$ is a divisor of $100$**.

If $p$ is a prime that ends on $3$ or $7$, then $2(p+1)$ is not divisible by $5$, so the only common divisor of $2(p+1)$ and $100$ is $1$, $2$ or $4$, but those are too small.

If $p$ is a prime that ends on $9$, then $p-1$ is not divisible by $5$, so the only common divisor of $p-1$ and $100$ is $1$, $2$ or $4$, but those are too small, again.

If $p$ is a prime that ends on $1$, the problem starts, since $10$ and sometimes $20$ are added to the list of possible common divisors. I guess, you have to write down the first $10$ or $20$ numbers from Pisano period for these numbers. For $11$: $$0,1,1,2,3,5,8,2,10,1.$$

We see that $F_1+F_{101}$ is $2$ modulo $11$. For $31$. Maximal common divisor of $30$ and $100$ is $10$, so we check the first $10$ Fibonacci numbers modulo $31$:

$$0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,3.$$

No second zero. For $61$ we will have to write down the first $20$ numbers:

$$0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,28,22,50,11,0.$$

We got zero, but $15$ isn’t a divisor of $100$. For $71$ we need $20$ numbers as well:

$$0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,18,2,20,22,42,64,35,28,63.$$

No second zero. Thus, the check is over. No other two-digit prime works.

Comment: Well first of all @Aig I m extremely sorry for not using mathjax as I m new to this community and I m still learning that tool so sorry for any inconvinience and I assure I would be learning that tool before my next question.Secondly as you pointed out that you have used a prerequisite of taking 41 your modulo, so do you mean that we have to check for every 2 digit prime independently and then build a recursion on top of it to solve such problems?

Comment: @AnayGautam It’s ok, we all learn, I just meant that MathJax is really easy. [This tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), while looking vast, is very useful. So I recommend storing it in bookmarks. About the problem: I cooked something, it’s still not very pretty, but I will now edit my answer to include my new reasoning.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added such reasoning.

Comment: Lovely! Thanks :) I now know those facts about the Pisano period.